# How to trigger jQuery counter when element is in window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, triggers

I have this jQuery code that triggers a counter from 0 to 1750. But, this counter is at the bottom of my page, and if you don't scroll to it quickly enough you miss the counter animation. Is there a way to trigger this to run only once you've hit the element in the window?

```
// Counter
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.count').each(function() {
        $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
            Counter: $(this).text()
        }, {
            duration: 12000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function(now) {
                $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The question you asked earlier has the code to solve this one to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, check your window top position and if is higher or equal of your target element and less the window height, then do your count animation.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper-count">
  <ul>
    <li class="count">0</li>
    <li class="count">0</li>
    <li class="count">0</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(function(){
    $(window).on("scroll", function(){
      var win_height = $(this).height();
      var win_pos    = $(this).scrollTop();
      var top_pos    = $(".wrapper-count").position().top;

      if(win_pos >= top_pos - win_height){
        // here goes your count logic
      }
    });
  });
});
```